# При выводе одной записи из базы методом getById($id) возвращает bool(false)

Tags: php, pdo, php7

При выводе одной записи из базы методом getById($id) возвращает bool(false) но метод getAll() работает нормально.

```
//файл db.php
class DB
{

    public static function connect()
    {
        $dsn = sprintf('%s:host=%s;dbname=%s', 'mysql', 'localhost', 'blog');
        return new PDO($dsn, 'root', '');
    }
}




//файл postModel.php

class postModel 
{
    private $db;
    private $nameTable = 'news';

    public function __construct(PDO $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function getAll()
    {
        $sql = sprintf('SELECT * FROM %s', $this->nameTable);
        $stmt = $this->db->query($sql);

        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }

    public function getById($id)
    {
        $sql = sprintf('SELECT * FROM %s WHERE id_new = :id', $this->nameTable);

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute([
            'id' => $id
        ]);

        return $stmt->fetch();
    }
}
```

Как вивожу на екран:

```
//файл index.php
include_once('db.php');
include_once('postModel.php');

$db = DB::connect(); 
$mPost = new postModel($db);
$news = $mPost->getById(1);

var_dump($news);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = sprintf('SELECT * FROM %s WHERE id_new = :id', $this->table);
```

Тут с `$this->table` напутали (`$this->nameTable` должно быть).

Comment: Исправил но дальше выдает bool(false)

Comment: А если без подготовленных выражений (просто вставить значения в текст), то что выдаёт? (Чисто для отладки)

Comment: Пробовал, тоже соме (bool (false)). Может это что-то может быть с таблицей в базе? Потому что сам код то рабочий.

Comment: id_new - в таблице точно столбец так называется?

Comment: Если так то все хорошо    public function getById($id)
 {
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM news WHERE id_new = 3';

  $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute([
   'id' => $id
  ]);

  return $stmt->fetch();
 }

Comment: sql запрос в методе записал $sql = 'SELECT * FROM news WHERE id_new = 3'; и все заработало.

Comment: почему то не работает execute